# Layout issue in webkit and moz

Tags: css

I have a layout issue in my web page where I have (for example:)

```
<div style="position:relative;width:500px;min-height:300px;background:red">
  <input type="text" style="position:absolute;top:20px;">
  <input type="buttton" style="position:absolute;bottom:2px;right:2px">
</div>
```

The positioning is slightly different in different browsers (say about 2-4 pixels). For example, the above button is a few pixels apart from the border in chrome or safari than firefox, seamonkey and opera. Is there a solution to this problem so that the layout looks almost same in different browsers?

Comment: thnkx @j08691 how is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset and unify your CSS first.
Checkout http://html5boilerplate.com/ for a good start on this.

Comment: oh thnkxx ,, let me see